# Tkinter: How to stop typing in an Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I want to be able to type something in an entry widget and when I am done typing I want to be able to click anywhere on the application to stop typing. As of right now it wants me to constantly type something into the entry box. Anyone know of a way to stop this?

```
import tkinter as tk

class window2:
    def __init__(self, master1):
        self.panel2 = tk.Frame(master1)
        self.panel2.grid()
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.panel2,text="Button")
        self.button1.grid()
        self.text1 = tk.Entry(self.panel2)
        self.text1.grid()
        self.text1.focus()

root1 = tk.Tk()
root1.geometry("750x500")
window2(root1)
root1.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could bind the mouse click to a function/method that sets focus to whatever you just clicked on.

Comment: What do you mean by "it wants me to constantly type something"? That doesn't seem to make sense: tkinter doesn't care if you type something or not.

Comment: Mike - SMT got it for me, thanks

Comment: @BryanOakley he was talking about the focus always being in the entry field even when he clicks off of the entry field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build this as an inherited class for `Tk` and then bind mouse button 1 to change focus to whatever widget was clicked.

```
import tkinter as tk

class window2(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("750x500")
        panel2 = tk.Frame(self)
        panel2.grid()
        tk.Button(panel2,text="Button").grid()
        text1 = tk.Entry(panel2)
        text1.grid()
        text1.focus()
        self.bind("<1>", self.set_focus)

    def set_focus(self, event=None):
        x, y = self.winfo_pointerxy()
        self.winfo_containing(x, y).focus()


window2().mainloop()
```